# Change sticky note annotation icon size created with PDFTron Android

Tags: pdftron

[image]

The sticky note annotation icon added with PDFTron looks quite small, Is there any way to change it.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so, did you try my proposed solution?

Comment: Your below solution solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already, you should update to the latest version of PDFNet as the default size might have changed since the version you are using.

Either way, you can use [PDFViewCtrl.setDevicePixelDensity](http://www.pdftron.com/api/android/pdfnet/javadoc/reference/com/pdftron/pdf/PDFViewCtrl.html#setDevicePixelDensity(double,%20double)) to adjust the size of the note. This function allows you to adjust depending on the device if you like.

For example

```
double deviceDensity = 1.0; // Scale relative to the internal DPI of 96 (default 1.0).
mPdfViewCtrl.setDevicePixelDensity(deviceDensity, 1);
```